# how to model category->product->variant tables in my multivendor marketplace database

Tags: database, e-commerce, product, categories, variant

i have the following tables in my mind for my product database, but i'm not sure how to design them according to this structure: category->product->variant
by the way, the prices change per each item, component, service, fabric and the vendor.

1. item group          : upper body, lower body, full body
2. item                : jacket, skirt, dress
3. item VS item group  : jacket -> upper body, skirt -> lower body, dress -> full body
4. component           : bust, hem
5. component VS item   : bust -> jacket, dress, hem -> skirt, dress
6. service group       : fixing, down-sizing, up-sizing
7. service             : zipper works, narrowing, lengthening
8. service VS s.group  : zipper works -> fixing, narrowing -> down-sizing, lengthening -> up-sizing
9. component VS service: bust -> zipper works, narrowing, lengthening, hem -> narrowing, lengthening
10. fabric             : cotton, leather
11. fabric VS item     : cotton -> jacket, skirt, dress, leather -> jacket, skirt, dress

i tried the following, but then one of my friends told me that i have to define all sellable products/services as 'variants', which made me so confused..

- category                    : item group
- subcategory-1               : item
- subcategory-2               : component
- subcategory-3               : service group
- product                     : service
- variant                     : fabric
- join/subcategory-1 & 2      : component VS item
- join/subcategory-2 & product: component VS service
- join/subcategory-1 & variant: fabric VS item
- other joins are solved by foreign keys

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.